# Putting a modified submodule in your repository on Github

Tags: git, git-submodules

I am working on an assignment for a class where my professor has created a fork of MIT's xv6 OS and I need to work with a partner on the assignment through github. So I set up a private repository to do it and I put the xv6 I was working on inside of a parent folder. Now I added the submodule to .gitmodules and the only problem is I don't know how to set up the submodule in .gitmodules in order to get my local xv6 rather than my instructors fork so my partner can see what I am doing.

Comment: Check out the submodule chapter in the progit book ( http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules ) That should help.